# ¿Como mostrar una imagen de carga como modal con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen/gif de pre carga cuando hago una acción de envio unos datos por AJAX, en la sección de beforesend llamo a un div y me muestra la imagen cargando una parte de mi formulario, mi pregunta es como podría hacer para que esa imagen de precarga se muestre en toda la pantalla con un fondo medio opaco y en el medio la imagen de carga. Algo como la imagen que estoy mostrando a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la sección de mi AJAX:
Donde en beforeSend, indico que el div que tiene la imagen de carga se muestre ya que en mi HTML lo tengo oculto como display:none, document.getElementById('PageLoadProgress').style.display = "block";

```
$.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                data: { dataSend: dataSend, objetos: objetos },
                url: '/material',
                beforeSend: function(){   
                    btn_m.disabled = true;  
                    document.getElementById('PageLoadProgress').style.display = "block";        
                },
                statusCode: {
                    422: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    200: function (response) {
                        console.log(response['success']);
                        document.getElementById('PageLoadProgress').style.display = "none"; 
                        if (response['success']['tubos'][0] == 1) {
                            let newRow = tableBody.insertRow(-1);
                            let count = tableBody.rows.length;
                            newRow.innerHTML = '<th scope="row">' + count + '</th><input type="hidden" class="material_id" name="material_id" value="' + response['success']['tubos'][0] + '"><td class="fw-bold">' + response['success']['tubos'][1] + '</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold quantity" id="cantidadTubos" name="cantidad" readonly value=' + response['success']['tubos'][2] + '> tubos</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold parts" name="piezas" readonly value=' + response['success']['tubos'][3] + '> x rollo</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold inches" name="pulgadas" readonly value=' + response['success']['tubos'][4] + '> tuberia</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold total_material" name="total-material" readonly value=' + response['success']['tubos'][5] + '> rollos</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor sale_price" name="precio" placeholder="Ingresar precio">dolares</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold costo_total" id="total_cost_tube" name="costo-total" readonly placeholder="$0.00"></td><td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_material(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>';
                        }
                        if (response['success']['laminas'][0] == 2) {
                            let newRow = tableBody.insertRow(-1);
                            let count = tableBody.rows.length;
                            newRow.innerHTML = '<th scope="row">' + count + '</th><input type="hidden" class="material_id" name="material_id" value="' + response['success']['laminas'][0] + '"><td class="fw-bold">' + response['success']['laminas'][1] + '</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold quantity" id="cantidadLaminas" name="cantidad" readonly value=' + response['success']['laminas'][2] + '> láminas</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold parts" name="piezas" readonly value=' + response['success']['laminas'][3] + '> x plancha</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold inches" name="pulgadas" readonly value=' + response['success']['laminas'][4] + '> láminas</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold total_material" name="total-material" readonly value=' + response['success']['laminas'][5] + '> metros</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor sale_price" name="precio" placeholder="Ingresar precio">dolares</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold costo_total" id="total_cost_lamina" name="costo-total" readonly placeholder="$0.00"></td><td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_material(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>';
                        }
                        btn_m.disabled = false;
                    },
                    500: function () {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Este es mi HTML donde tengo oculto mi div con la imagen cargada y me muestra en una parte de mi formulario, lo que quisiera es como poder mostrar el gif de carga al medio y con fondo medio opaco como lo hacen los modales, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

```
<form action="" method="">
   <div id="PageLoadProgress" class="p-2" style="display:none;margin-left:155px;border:#014c8d 1px solid;background-color:#eeeeee"><img src="{{asset('images/gif/Progress-circle.gif')}}" alt="Progress"><span class="ml-1" style="color: #0069A5;font-size:12.5px">Cargando...</span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero `block ui`.

Comment: RobertoLeOr, gracias acabo de ver los demos de block ui, podria incluir sus funciones dentro del beforeSend de mi ajax? y se muestre como carga antes de tener respuesta del servidor o como lo implementarias porfs

Comment: Saludos. Sí; yo uso `$.blockUI({ message:'el mensaje a mostrar'})` y `$.unblockUI();`; el primero para mostrar el mensaje (mientras la operación `ajax` esta en curso) y la segunda para quitarlo (indistintamente éxito, completo, error....); solo cuida que tu `z-index` en la modal no sea muy alto o forza al `baseZ` de `blockUI` a uno muy alto. Se puede personalizar lo que mostrara al momento y mientras esté presente en la pantalla. https://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: RobertoLeOr, acabo de implementar el blockUI me funciona bien, lo estoy usando en la plantilla AdminLTE, el cual tiene un formulario..pero cuando muestro esa seccion de mi pagina solo pone opaco esa seccion y no toda pantalla..como podria hacer que muestre en toda la pantalla?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. usando `$.blockUI` lo hace en toda la pantalla; si estas usando `$('#elemento').block` **element blocking** (https://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element) es lo que genera el efecto que mencionas. Aunque creo recordar en algunos casos la parte del menú no lo cubría; pero así lo deje ya que fue presentación; creo no recuerdo bien si lo solucione y como.